# BaseOutputPath bug in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)

> **BaseOutputPath**: Specifies the base path for the output file. If it is
>   set, MSBuild will use OutputPath =
>   $(BaseOutputPath)\$(Configuration)\

I tried to use the MSBuild Project Property *BaseOutputPath* instead of specifying *OutputPath* for every configuration & platform combination but Visual Studio complains when I compile:

> The OutputPath property is not set for
>   this project.  Please check to make
>   sure that you have specified a valid
>   Configuration/Platform combination.

I put `<BaseOutputPath>..\Binaries</BaseOutputPath>` in the first unconditional `<ProjectProperty>`.

Am I using it incorrectly, or is this a known bug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more likely a bug in the docs than in VS2008/MSBuild.

You can always reason out what you want to do with (greuling) inspection of e.g. your project file and the Microsoft.Common.Targets file it imports (typically through e.g. Microsoft.CSharp.targets; these files live at e.g.

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets

) and find all the MSBuild logic that eventually populates OutputPath.

In this case, I think the docs are lying outright, and you should e.g. explicitly say

```
<OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
```

in unconditional properties of your project file (and remove OutputPath from conditional properties) to make this work.

Comment: I see, but this then really negates the benefit of using BaseOutputPath in the first place. I could just use <OutputPath>..\Binaries\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>. Thanks for the clarification!